# Setting Div Content to property of JSON Object results in html tags showing on screen

Tags: jquery, html, json, umbraco

I have an umbraco macro that spits out the content of the page at http://cleanfeed.mysolutionuk.com/projects

All works well, but when I try to set the content of a div to the property of the JSON object (parsed from raw html in a hidden div), the output shows the actual text, rather than interpreting it as html.  You can see the result by clicking the tile in the demo url.

In summary:

```
var jsonString = $(dataElementId).html();
var data = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

//Set Properties of Player with the selected project:
$("#projectCompanyLogo").attr("src", data.ProjectCompanyLogoUrl);
$("#smallTitlePg").html(data.SmallTitle);
$("#mainTitlePg").html(data.MainTitle);

//Change the content of a div to the data in project description, should show as pure html:     
$("#flexScrollDynamicContent").html(unescape(data.ProjectDescription).replace('"',''));
$("#projectContent").attr("style", data.RightColumnBg);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong...  But when the content is set, you see the physical `<p>` and `&nbsp;` tags on the screen, rather than it being rendered as HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
$("#flexScrollDynamicContent").html($('<div/>').html(data.ProjectDescription).text());
```

This essentially makes jQuery decode html entities (which are in your Json string), for example:

```
$('<div/>').html("&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;").text();
```

gives:

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a million... spot on.  I'm new to this jquery stuff.. just coming out of the server side / web forms world!